# dotnetcore Nuget enable Pre-Release

Tags: nuget, .net-core, dotnet-cli

I've started using dotnetcore for a hobby project.

I'm having an issue trying to install NLog. The Visual Studio Code editor seems to recognise the beta version as the intelisense suggests it inside the project.json file. However nuget doesn't seem to restore it.

Is there a way to enable pre-release on Nuget packages in the new dotnet core platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across the answer to my question whilst watching a PluralSight video on Entity Framework Core By Dr Scott Allen.

One option is to use the visual studio package manager console and use the -pre flag. e.g:

`install-package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.tools -pre`

Answer (score 0):

Is the package on the Nuget repo? Check this link to see if its listed:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog

If it's on there you can just add it to your project.json and then run a dotnet restore to install the nuget, no intellisense required.

Comment: yes the package is listed on the nuget site. Adding the package is a problem because it's a pre-release. Nuget by default usually needs an enable pre-release flag however I am using dotnet core so I'm not sure how to enable pre-release in a dotnet core environment. Unfortunately this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: just to clarify, adding to json file doesn't work as the package isn't found... .Pre-release needs to be enabled